# Make chatter feeds created by Process builder accessible to Community User

Tags: process-builder

I am using process builder to create chatter feeds on a custom object and mentioning a community user. 
Now in salesforce that chatter feed is available, but in community it isn't visible to that user .

The problem here is i have to manually edit that feed and make it visible to all.
Is there any way to do this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share process builder where you create chatter feed

Comment: updated pic for clarification.

Comment: Do your community users have at least read access on your custom object, as in has it been exposed to your community?

Comment: Yes they have. They can even post feeds.